# Active Directory Powershell - Get OU details

Tags: powershell

Below is the code: PowerShell 2.0

```
$DomainDN = Get-ADDomain -Server $svr | Select DistinguishedName | Out-String
$CountryDN = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Server $svr -LDAPFilter '(name=Countries)' -SearchBase '$DomainDN' -SearchScope 0 | Select DistinguishedName | Out-String
```

Upon execution I get the below error:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following partition(s): 'CN=Configuration,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , CN=Sche
ma,CN=Configuration,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , DC=eul,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , DC=DomainDns
Zones,DC=eul,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com'.
At line:3 char:38
+ $CountryDN = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit <<<<  -Server $svr -LDAPFilter '(name=Countries)' -SearchBase '$DomainDN' -SearchScope 0 | Select DistinguishedName | Out-String
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following partition(s): 'CN=Configuration,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , CN= 
   Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , DC=eul,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com , DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com ,
   DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=eul,DC=lab,DC=mydomain,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrganizationalUnit
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$domainDN = get-addomain -server $svr | 
  select-object -expandproperty DistinguishedName
$countryDN = get-adorganizationalunit -server $svr -ldapfilter '(name=Countries)' `
  -searchbase $domainDN | select-object -expandproperty DistinguishedName
```

select-object -expandproperty will return a string rather than a PSObject so you don't need out-string.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

```
$DomainDN = Get-ADDomain -Server $svr | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

or

```
$DomainDN = (Get-ADDomain -Server $svr).DistinguishedName
```